# Can hydrogen be generated from flowing water?

Tags: energy, water, electromagnetic-induction, hydrogen

Imagine water (water is made conductive using salt) flowing at a great speed is passed through a high magnetic field.
Then due to changing flux , can we induce electric current in water? If electric current can be induced in water, then  could we separate hydrogen and oxygen from water by doing electrolysis with the induced current?

Comment: Closely related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetohydrodynamic_converter

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would be possible although it would be very hard. It would be just like doing normal electrolysis with a few modifications and running water instead of the water being still. This is a link for some more information although it is not exactly what you wanted: https://cen.acs.org/physical-chemistry/Magnet-doubles-hydrogen-yield-water/97/web/2019/06